# OverWriting URL using angular resource not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I am using angular resource in order to retrieve a record from my AP.
Below is my relevant controller information.

```
$scope.formInformation = formService.get({id:$state.params.form_id });
```

Below is my service

```
    (function(){
        "use strict";

        angular
        .module("mainAppModule")
        .factory("formService", formService);

        function formService($resource)
        {
            return $resource(apiLink + 'form/:id',
                //{id: '@_id'}, //this breaks it
                {
                    'query' : {
                    method: 'GET',
                    isArray: true,
                    }
                },
                {
                    'get' : {
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: apiLink + 'form/individualForm/:id',


                    }
                }
            );
        }
    })();
```

When I try to overwrite the url variable, it still uses the original one which is.

```
"apiLink +"form/:id"
```

as opposed to

```
apiLink + 'form/individualForm/:id',
```

which should be overwritten by the following line.

```
 url: apiLink + 'form/individualForm/:id',
```

but when I remove.

```
{id:'@id'},
```

My url is overwritten.
I am trying to understand why that is the case.
I am using angular and angular resource version 1.7.7.

Comment: Please include the code you use to "overwrite the url variable". And explain what you mean when you say "uses the original one".

Comment: Updated my question. url is what is used to overwrite the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `actions` parameter is malformed:

```
    function formService($resource)
    {
        return $resource(apiLink + 'form/:id',
            //{id: '@_id'}, //this breaks it
            {
                'query' : {
                method: 'GET',
                isArray: true,
                }
            ̶ ̶}̶,̶
            ̶{̶
                'get' : {
                method: 'GET',
                url: apiLink + 'form/individualForm/:id',

                }
            }
        );
    }
```

The `actions` parameter should be a hash of all the resource actions. When the actions were spread over two objects, only the first object overrode the default. The action declaration for `get` was ignored and the default was used.